# How to use the .append() with a dynamic variable ID?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, loops

I am looking for a way to loop throw all select tags, see there queries, id, class, metadata, ect and use that data to pass to my AJAX GET request. appending the successful response to the corresponding tag in the loop. I am stuck and would love some pointers, or ideas to do this cleaner. I do not know the elements tags or classes until after DOM is loaded.

Edit: I have figure out how to loop through all the tags, however when it comes down to appending to the tag I am having issues. the following line works for one select with the id C31: `$("#1C3").append("<option value='" + value + "'>" + value + "</option>");` However the following does not work and I am trying to find a solution to use a variable instead of the '#c31'. how can I pass the correct parameters of my ID to $(?).append() `

```
 var elementID = classList[i].id;
   var temp = '#';
   var result = temp.concat(elementID);
    console.log(typeof result);
    $(result).append("<option value='" + value + "'>" + value + "</option>");
```

`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 for(i = 0; i< classListSize; i++){
    var elementID = classList[i].id;
    var temp = '#';
    var result = temp.concat(elementID);

    if(classList[i].tagName === 'SELECT'){
      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:9000/LabData', //In future we need to make this to be able to pass any params as so we can get anything from db
        type: 'GET', //SELECT ProjectName FROM Projects
        datatype: "json",
        success: (data) => { //it was succesful in getting data
          var dt = JSON.stringify(data).replace('[', '').replace(']', '');
          if (dt) {
            var result = jQuery.parseJSON(dt);
            for (x in dt) {
              var temp = result.recordset[x]
              for (key in temp) {
                var value = temp[key];
                //console.log("result : ", value);
                $(result).append("<option value='" + value + "'>" + value + "</option>");
                //do something with value;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: what's url? also need html with which you are interacting

Comment: your code is not complete ! also you did not tell us about your problem, are you getting an error ...

Comment: I updated the url: which goes to a web service I run to grab data from ms sql.  I believe the title lays out my problem, which is: I trying to figure a way out to loop through all tags that are select, and pass data for each one to the ajax GET function.

Comment: I see that the dt is a string. So if you loop a string you will get all characters, but i think you want to loop as json obj or array to get all elements/tags and then you do what you want. It will be better to provide example data. I insert it as an answer as it does not allow me to add a comment.